# WHM API: emailtrack_search returns empty records

Tags: json, api, cpanel, whm, exim

I am using the WHM api to track emails in the mail delivery log, however, the JSON response using emailtrack_search return no records

I am calling the following URL

```
1xx.x.xx.xxx:2087/cpsess####/json-api/emailtrack_search?api.version=1
```

And this is the JSON response

```
{"metadata":{"result":1,"version":1,"command":"emailtrack_search","reason":"OK","overflowed":0,"__chunked":1},"data":{"records":[]}}
```

Notice that the records are empty, but i have messages in the email delivery log, I tried adding a user as parameter but it returns the same.

Does anybody know how to show email delivery logs using this API?

I would really appreciate any help

Best regards.

Comment: I could fix the issue adding a parameter add the end, thanks to cpanel support, you need to set what type of emails you need to get:

Comment: 1xx.x.xx.xxx:2087/cpsess####/json-api/emailtrack_search?api.version=1&defer=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread might help you. Also you can ask for request on cPanel forums. There are a lot of active users there:

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/track-delivery-api.534501/

Answer (score 1):

Daniel, the empty records array was driving me crazy as well. Your findings helped me dig deeper into cPanel's badly documented API. To help others looking for similar answers, I detailed the process in a blog post - [Email delivery reports using WHM API and PHP](https://www.warrenasia.com/blog/how-to/generate-email-delivery-reports-using-php-and-whm-api/)

**Edit:** Here's a piece of my code that returns results from WHM's JSON API, using *emailtrack_search*:

```
function fetchRecordsByHour($sender, $startTime, $endTime) {
  //Set up variables
  $user = USER;
  $token = TOKEN;
  $hostname = HOSTNAME;

  //Set up query - https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/DD/WHM+API+1+Functions+-+emailtrack_search
  $query = $hostname.'/json-api/emailtrack_search?api.version=1'.
            '&api.filter.enable=1'. //Enable filter (https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/DD/WHM+API+1+-+Filter+Output)
            '&api.filter.a.field=sender&api.filter.a.arg0='.$sender.'&api.filter.a.type=eq'. //Filter records with $sender
            '&api.filter.b.field=sendunixtime&api.filter.b.arg0='.$startTime.'&api.filter.b.type=gt'. //Filter records greater than $startTime
            '&api.filter.c.field=sendunixtime&api.filter.c.arg0='.$endTime.'&api.filter.c.type=lt'. //Filter records less than $endTime
            '&api.sort.enable=1'. //Enable sorting (https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/DD/WHM+API+1+-+Sort+Output)
            '&api.sort.a.field=sendunixtime&api.sort.a.method=numeric&api.sort.a.reverse=0'. //Sort by sent time, not in reverse (By default, the API sorts in reverse order)
            '&success=1'. //Fetch success emails
            '&defer=1'. //Fetch defered emails
            '&failure=1'. //Fetch failed emails
            '&inprogress=1'. //Fetch in progress emails
            '&deliverytype=all'. //Fetch remote and local emails
            '&max_results_by_type=999'; // Fetch a large number of records per batch (Since WHM limits the total at 250 records, anything above 250 is fine)

  //Initialize CURL
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $query);

  //Set authentication parameters
  $header[0] = "Authorization: whm $user:$token";
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

  $result = curl_exec($curl);

  //Check for CURL error
  $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  if ($http_status != 200) {
    echo "Error: ".$http_status." returned";
  }

  curl_close($curl);

  //Return only the records, stripping away all the metadata
  return json_decode($result)->data->records;
}
```